# Wagtailstreamforms TypeError from_db_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Tags: django, forms, wagtail

I got this error when trying to use wagtailstreamforms. Built a from-scratch environment and reproduced the error. The only things I installed:

```
Django==3.0.5
wagtail==2.8
wagtailstreamforms==3.9
```

In base.py added (as prescribed in docs):

```
    'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
    'wagtailstreamforms'
```

Left everything else untouched (standard Wagtail base.py), migrated database. Home page 127.0.0.1:8000 gives Wagtail's welcome page as expected, admin is at 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ with Streamforms item in menu on the left as expected. When I click on it, I can make a form and when I make the first field for the form and then save it, I get the error above. After that I cannot access the Streamforms section anymore, I immediately get the same error when I try.

I looked through all posts on SO on wagtailstreamforms and many similar items on the internet, no solution. What am I doing wrong?

Complete error log:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/wagtailstreamforms/form/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templatetags/modeladmin_tags.py", line 94, in result_list
    'results': list(results(view, object_list))})
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templatetags/modeladmin_tags.py", line 74, in results
    for item in object_list:
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 74, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/Users/paulsmits/Code/MyCompany/streamformserror/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1095, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
TypeError: from_db_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
[12/Apr/2020 19:32:19] "GET /admin/wagtailstreamforms/form/ HTTP/1.1" 500 304823
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer. Wagtailstreamforms is not yet supporting Django 3.0, although that is not mentioned in the docs. There is one change which is apparently scheduled but not yet pushed which causes the error, see https://github.com/timonweb-forks/wagtailstreamforms/commit/57ff036593b43f4dd7926412d0075cefb934e5e5. After manually changing this in my env, everything works. I'll let the developers know.